# Adding smileys in sms application

Tags: android, sms

I have a sms app which does the basic functions.I want to add some smileys so that user can send sms with smileys same as Handcent app.

How can i do this?

Thanks in Advance

Regards-Sunny

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using ImageSpan objects. The TextViews and EditTexts use Spanned/Spannable objects to store the entered text content, not just mere java Strings. On these Spanned/Spannable objects you can define spans for sections on the text that modifies the way that those sections are shown. So you can display a text in bold, italics, etc. and you can also display images in place of certain sections.

This way you can search for a ":-)" pattern in the entered text, and slap an ImageSpan on it displaying a smiley. Check the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ImageSpan.html).